# ValueError: node 'Placeholder' in input_map does not exist in graph (input_map entry: input_image:0->Placeholder:0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

**Minimal Code:**

```
# load model
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(args.model, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
            generated_image_1, generated_image_2, generated_image_3, = tf.import_graph_def(
                    graph_def, 
                    input_map={'input_image' : input_tensor, 'short_edge_1' : short_edge_1, 'short_edge_2' : short_edge_2, 'short_edge_3' : short_edge_3}, 
                    return_elements=['style_subnet/conv-block/resize_conv_1/output:0', 'enhance_subnet/resize_conv_1/output:0', 'refine_subnet/resize_conv_1/output:0'], 
                    name=None, 
                    op_dict=None, 
                    producer_op_list=None  *#line number 55*
                )
    
    short_edges = [int(e) for e in args.hierarchical_short_edges.split(',')]
```

**Error:**

```
(myenv) D:\subbu>python file.py --model=models/model.pb --input_image=test_images/image.jpg
2021-12-25 00:54:11.765889: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
input image -  test_images/image.jpg (1200, 630, 3)
WARNING:tensorflow:From file.py:55: calling import_graph_def (from tensorflow.python.framework.importer) with op_dict is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please file an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues if you depend on this feature.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subbu\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 501, in _import_graph_def_internal
    graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: node 'Placeholder' in input_map does not exist in graph (input_map entry: input_image:0->Placeholder:0)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "file.py", line 55, in main
    producer_op_list=None
  File "C:\Users\subbu\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\subbu\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 405, in import_graph_def
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "C:\Users\subbu\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\importer.py", line 505, in _import_graph_def_internal
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: node 'Placeholder' in input_map does not exist in graph (input_map entry: input_image:0->Placeholder:0)
```

I was running file.py but still it is not running, I did some changes in source file. Still placeholder error is same.
The code is also updated with this question.
Kindly review and Help.

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: @shivankgtm I updated the full error.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I added the code part too.